# Can we find another data type that is smaller than float?

Tags: c, types, floating-point

I allocated the following buffer in order to store values between `0-1` exclusive:

```
float *buff = malloc(n* sizeof(float))
```

However, I think using `float` makes no freedom of choosing large `n`, say `n=10,000`, when allocating in small memory size. Since the size of float is `32 bit`, I wonder if there is another way to reduce this size by workaround or choosing another data type.

Comment: On many systems `char` is a smaller datatype. And the size of `float` is not necessarily 32 bits (it cannot be less due to the min. required range, though)

Comment: @Olaf - OP is looking for a smaller representation of values between 0 and 1, not 0 and 1.

Comment: @owacoder: A `char` (and any other integer) can easily represent fractional values. But `10,000` is an integer. Note this is an English-speaking site and `,` is not a decimal point!

Comment: @Olaf - Yes, but not without additional work. And assigning a floating-point constant (between 0 and 1) to an integer will not behave the same as assigning to a floating-point type.

Comment: @owacoder: It is not **that** complicated. The standard library provides helpers to support that. Also some compilers have support for fractional types and smaller floating point types. Especially embedded compilers (and gcc for some architectures). On x86/64 or the larger ARM CPUs such "optimisations" are often nonsense and just worsen things. Anyway, it is not clear what OPs actual problem is. Without further information, it seems to be an XY-problem. If he is on an MCU without FPU, the fractional approach is most likely the correct way.

Comment: Dropping the exponent and aiming for a custom fixed-point representation would get my vote.  Rolling your own 24-bit type or going down to 16-bit with the standard `uint16_t`. However, this would be based on a presumption that your data precision has a fixed number of decimal places, rather than significant figures. If you require additional precision as you get closer to zero, fixed-point will not be suitable. Either way, the description of  the problem smells of premature optimization to me.  You seem to be unsure about whether the freedom of n=10000 is necessary, or what problem it creates.

Comment: If you are on a system where 40.000 octets are a true problem, you most likely should first not use dynamic memory allocation with `malloc` at all. They have too much problems on such small devices. TGhen, such systems typically don't have an FPU, thus using standard `float` is almost always a bad idea. Add some more work and use integers as fixed-point. The exact scale depends on your application required precision and other aspects.

Comment: @paddy: Most people overestimate the necessary precision. But with 16 bits one can also quite easily emulate an optimised floating point type. (e.g. 11 + 1 bit mantissa, 4 exponent). Such formats are typically still faster than standard `float`.

Comment: To summarise: "I think" is a bad basis for a proper design. First make sure you **know**. Then think about how to implement.

Comment: @Olaf [How the world separates its decimals](http://www.statisticalconsultants.co.nz/blog/how-the-world-separates-its-decimals.html) supports the idea _most_ English speaking countries use `'.'`.  At least [South Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_South_Africa) an exception.

Comment: @chux: In germany we use `,`, too. But I apparently confused the `10,000` with the float range anyway (and messed up with the German version in my comment above: `40.000`). But I think the context is clear and the text is correct. Anyway, the C standard is clear and that's our anchor.

Comment: Step one is to identify the set of values that must be stored and distinguished from each other. That will control the minimum number of bits, and best choice of encoding.

Answer (score 6):

C has no floating-point type smaller than `float`.

There are several integer types that are likely (but not guaranteed) to be smaller than `float`:

- `signed char`
- `unsigned char`
- `signed short`
- `unsigned short`

Of course the `unsigned` types can't hold negative values, and none of then can hold fractional values.

You can always define your own type(s), or for example just interpret a `signed char` value (which will typically be in the range `-128` .. `+127`) as a fractional value. I've seen 16-bit floating-point layouts, thought they're not directly supported by C or by most hardware.

Be aware that the size of the additional code to perform the scaling might exceed the data size you save. On the other hand, code and data size are not necessarily interchangeable.

It would be much easier to answer your question if we knew more about both the range and the precision of the values you want to represent.

Note that unless you're on a small embedded system, allocating an array of 10,000 `float` objects is likely to be trivial. Don't expend too much effort on using a smaller type unless you're sure it's necessary.